# Why do my images break in Visual Studio when they have the word "order" in them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image

I've been banging my head trying to find the cause of why my images weren't loading, heres my basic work flow.

- create image in Photoshop CS5
- export for web/device (PNG/GIF/JPG)
- save to images folder
- drag the images into visual studio with the
  rest of them

Now I've been using this method for a very long time, and after returning from holidays I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working any more. When the page loads it shows the missing image icon. Firebug couldn't locate the image, CSS was not reading it neither would an `<img>` tag.

A LONG time later it turns out I found the root cause, my image was named "order_header_bg.png" if I dropped the word "order" from the title it appeared!

I can't figure out why its doing it, I can't find any docs on image naming conventions, so the only work around is not to include the word. Its not a problem but I'm more curious as to why is doesn't behave as expected. Is this unique to my environment?

Comment: You really need to post some of your HTML/Code for us to make any sense of this.

Comment: its not a coding issue, the code won't benefit the cause, the code works fine IF I dont have "order" in the image name. However if you would like an example here you go <img src="../images/order_header_bg.png"></img> this in a webpage would result in a broken image, even though its included in the project, and located in the right folder.

Comment: ... rename the image to foo.png and edit the tag to this <img src="../images/foo.png"></img> and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: Its goosed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any ad-blocking software installed on your machine?  They can be rather aggressive about what they block.

I had a client who had Norton Ad Blocker installed and was reporting that she could not see the navigation on her site.  Her particular problem was that she was running an advertising agency, and thus all of her links were deemed as spam.

Comment: It's much funnier in retrospect.  Wasn't fun at the time :D

Comment: haha thats great. I have F-Secure anti-virus and I'm behind a company firewall, although its running from localhost and accessing files from C:\ so it shouldn't be a problem? Image is broken in IE, Chrome and Firefox so its not a browser issue either by the looks :(

Comment: Well, that depends.  I know the Skype plugin that gets installed likes to spread itself liberally over all my browsers. Also, some plug-ins aren't clever enough to distinguish between local and external use.